# JavaScript: XML DOM Load Error

Tags: javascript

i have a problem to load an xml file (XML DOM Load),using JavaScript
so,whene i do this:

```
var xmlFile=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
```

it load correct and i can use and exploit it.
but whene i spécifie the xml filename to load from an input value(XML fileName to load=input value) like this: its dosn't work and i need a solution please

---

```
...
var usr = document.getElementById('user').value+".xml";   //exemple:if (input id="user" value)="test", the result is "test.xml"
var xmlFile=loadXMLDoc(usr);   //load "test.xml" file
...
```

---

its dosn't work and i need a solution please

Comment: How are you executing the JavaScript? Has the HTML DOM loaded?

Comment: Just want to make sure on this, are you trying to get the value from a file input element?

Comment: yeah the loadXMLDoc() load correct,and when i call a simple file "test.xml" it's load normale correct and i can use it, but when i try to get the file name from the input value and concat this name white ".xml" like this (var usr = document.getElementById('user').value+".xml";) it's dosn't work when i use "usr" :(

Comment: what is `document.getElementById('user')` - I mean is there only 1 control with this ID? What type of control is it? Can you show your html?